# Add roles to users in specific guild through DM

Tags: discord.js

When I try

`message.member.roles.add('695699359634817094');`

I get the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined`

Is there a specific way to add my guild ID and update their role to that specific server through DM?

My function works within the guild by calling the command, however, through DM it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by using `message.author.id` to get the user's ID and then using `guild.get(guild_ID).members.fetch(user_ID)` to access the `GuildMember` of that user.

You also mentioned that you give users the ability to run that command either in DM or a text channel in your guild.

If that is the case I would suggest adding a check to see if the command is being sent to a text channel or dm channel.

```js
if (message.channel.type === "dm") {
    const member = await client.guilds.get(guild_ID).members.fetch(message.author.id);
    member.roles.add(role_ID);
} else {
    message.member.roles.add('695699359634817094');
}
```

Ignore the if statement if you intend on having the command only run from dm.

Comment: okay, thank you for trying to help me! ive got the guild function working now, however when i make a call its stating member.roles.add('roleidhere')  TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Comment: Console log member

Comment: Current code i got, not sure why its being weird.
   if (message.channel.type === "dm") {
    let member1 = client.guilds.get('695647616800915486').members.fetch(message.author.id);
    console.log(member1)
    member1.roles.add('695699359634817094');
   } else {
    message.member.roles.add('695699359634817094');
   }

Comment: It's returning a GuildMember, it should work, try console logging member1.roles

Comment: its coming back as undefined

Comment: `fetch` does not return a `GuildMember`, but a Promise that *resolves* into a `GuildMember` object. You would have to use `await`, like `const member1 = await client.guilds.get()...`, or `then()`, like `...fetch(id).then(member => //add role)`.

Comment: thank you ! i have fixed the function ill update the answer, thank you both

Answer (score 0):

By using the info given from Syntle and tipakA this is the solution.

```
if (message.channel.type === "dm") {
    client.guilds.get('[SeverId]').members.fetch(message.author.id).then(async () => {
        await client.guilds.get('[ServerId]').members.fetch(message.author.id).then((memberid) => {
            memberid.roles.add('[roleid]');
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log("ERROR");
        });
    });         
}
else 
{
    message.member.roles.add('[roleid]');
}
```